# android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>.Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

i have reviewed many threads about this error but it is not resolved. Finally, I exported everything in the manifest file, but this did not solve it either. Can you help me?

Console Error

```
Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
```

My Manifest File;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.educationyks.yksapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" tools:node="remove" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <queries android:exported="true">
        <intent android:exported="true">
            <action android:name="com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START" android:exported="true"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <application
        android:name=".ApplicationClass"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppFullScreenTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        <activity android:name=".ui.Forum.ForumMyPostsActivity"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity android:name=".ui.Forum.ForumTekliPostActivity"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.TekliSoruGosterActivity"
            android:exported="true"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_onesignal_default"
            android:exported="true"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"
            tools:replace="android:value"
            android:exported="true"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.DersVideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:exported="true"/>

        <activity android:name=".Activities.LoginActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:exported="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" android:exported="true"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" android:exported="true"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activities.UniversitySelectionActivity"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true"/>

        <receiver android:name=".Activities.AlarmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-2414658395986510~9865466288"
            android:exported="true"
            />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Merged Manifest;

[image: Merged Manifest Screenshot]

Lastly, All of my implementations are up-to-date. I tried all the methods that I can think of and read, but I can't find a solution. I request your help on the matter.

Comment: Only Activity/services/broadcast receivers required exported attribute. for launcher activity it should be true and false for rest of the components.

Comment: post your merged manifest as text, not screenshot of sum-upof all dependencies